# Bring variable value from Block to Global Scope (in FIRESTORE)

Tags: javascript, function, google-cloud-firestore, scope, global-scope

I'm creating an App in Firebase, using FireStore as my Database.

In the code below, I create a variable `order` and assign it a value of 1.

Then I update the value to the number 4 and `console.log` it to check. Which turns out fine.

But when I log the variable after the function, it returns 1 again, instead of the updated value.

**This is My code** (do See the  //comments)

```js
    console.log("Value initiated : " + order); // logs 'Value initiated : 1'

    //A function that gets another value from the FireStore Database and assigns it to the variable.
    function getField() {
      db.collection("index")
        .doc("artNum")
        .get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          order = doc.data().artNum; //I reassign the variable to '4' here.
          console.log("Value assigned : " + order); // logs 'Value assigned : 4'
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    getField(); 
    console.log("Updated Value : " + order); // logs " Updated Value : 1 " but should be equal to 4
```

> Please help me with what I'm doing wrong or what this code is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do `window.order = yourValue` (replace `window` with `global` if you are in node) to create a global `order` variable.

You also have to understand that your code is *asynchronous* which means that the updates will happen *after* your *getField* function is called. So looking for the new value will not work. However your *getFields* function returns a `Promise` that is always fulfilled (thanks to your `catch` clause).

So this should work

```
console.log("Value initiated : " + order); // logs 'Value initiated : 1'

//A function that gets another value from the FireStore Database and assigns it to the variable.
function getField() {
  return db.collection("index")
    .doc("artNum")
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      order = doc.data().artNum; //I reassign the variable to '4' here.
      console.log("Value assigned : " + order); // logs 'Value assigned : 4'
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

getField().then(() => console.log("Updated value", order));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend.
Basically I'm a newbie in web Development, and of course Javascript. And I'm not able to integrate this in my code.
Can you please update my code with this method. I'll be really thankful.

Comment: I read your code a bit fast and did not catch the async flow you are working with. My update should work. I suggest you look at the docs for Promises and chaining them and global variables (https://frontendmasters.com/courses/deep-javascript-v3/dynamic-global-variables/)

Comment: It's showing this error :

[https://i.ibb.co/5230w46/Fullscreen-capture-27-02-2020-190931.jpg](https://i.ibb.co/5230w46/Fullscreen-capture-27-02-2020-190931.jpg)
or  [https://ibb.co/st4fzR2](https://ibb.co/st4fzR2) .


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at app.js:80

Comment: I edited, you need to add the `return` clause in the `getField` function. sorry

Comment: Thanks buddy, This seems to work. But I wanted to use the value of the `order` variable outside the function.